# Postgresql LARGE query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I got some problems with my query in Postgresql. This query takes a long time to execute (about 30 sec without buffers) 
My query is here:

```
SELECT  d.name, COUNT (*) AS cnt,
            'first' AS TYPE
        FROM
            tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableD d ON d.NAME = 'FOO'
        AND a.key = d.key
        WHERE
            a.DATE > '2017-06-01'
        AND a.DATE < '2017-07-01'
        group by d.name
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        d.name,
        COUNT (*) AS cnt,
        'second' AS TYPE
    FROM
        tableB b
    INNER JOIN tableD d ON d.NAME = 'FOO'
    AND b.key = d.key
    WHERE
        b.DATE > '2017-06-01'
    AND b.DATE < '2017-07-01'
    group by d.name
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        d.name,
        COUNT (*) AS cnt,
        'Third' AS TYPE
    FROM
        tableC c
    INNER JOIN tableD d ON d.NAME = 'FOO'
    AND c.key = d.key
    WHERE
        c.date > '2017-06-01'
    AND c.date < '2017-07-01'
    group by d.name
```

I created indexes on tableC.key (Btree) and on tableC.name (Hash)
Moreover other tables have indexes on date and key (Btree)

So my query can join by indexes, and can filter by indexes

My tableD has a few thousands rows, others have billions or almost billions

In the execution plan i saw that the executor uses nested loops all of my joins (expect one at B-D join, there's a hash join)

Maybe i found the "betrayer"

```
Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
        "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
        "Relation Name": "tableA",
        "Alias": "a",
        "Startup Cost": 2469.84,
        "Total Cost": 137625.61,
        "Plan Rows": 53748,
        "Plan Width": 37,
        "Recheck Cond": "(((key)::text = (d.key)::text) AND (date > '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2017-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))",
                "Plans": [{
                    "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
                    "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                    "Index Name": "\"date + key\"",
                    "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                    "Total Cost": 2456.40,
                    "Plan Rows": 53748,
                    "Plan Width": 0,
                    "Index Cond": "(((key)::text = (d.key)::text) AND (date > '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2017-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
                            }]
```

TableD:

```
    CREATE TABLE "sch"."tableD" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "key" varchar(36) COLLATE "default",
    "name" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",


    CREATE INDEX "license_key" ON "sch"."tableD" USING btree ("key");
    CREATE INDEX "name" ON "sch"."tableD" USING btree ("name");
```

TableA:

```
    CREATE TABLE "sch"."tableA" (
    "id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('"sch".table'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    "key" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "date" timestamp(6),

    CREATE INDEX "date" ON "sch"."tableA" USING btree ("date");
    CREATE INDEX "date + key" ON "sch"."tableA" USING btree ("key", "date")
    CREATE INDEX "keyIndex" ON "sch"."tableA" USING btree ("key");
```

TableB and C similar to A

I have no idea, why I lose time exactly here. Can you help me solve my problem, This query should not run for 30 seconds
Thank you

Comment: Start by measuring how long each subquery takes.  Then you can narrow down the performance issue.

Comment: Unsure, but it looks to me we could eliminate the unions and have 1 query using a window function to get the count. and a case statement to set the types and outer joins.

Comment: the first subquery takes the longest time, but the most rows are in the tableA so I can imagine this may cause query's slowdown

If i eliminate my unions the executor can choose hash joins (or merged joins if I use hash indexes on keys) but it is more slower (100-120 secs)

Comment: can d.key exist in more than one table of A,b,C?

Comment: key is unique in D and in A,B,C its a foreign key to D (one to many relation)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`** (**text** format, no json, xml or yaml please).

Answer (score 0):

Provide these *BTree* indexes (*not* Hash):

```
b: (DATE, key)
b: (key, DATE)
d: (NAME, key)
d: (key, NAME)
```

It looks like a month's time span, yet you exclude the beginning of the month.  Change `>` to `>=`.